# andengine entity modifier advanced effects

Tags: android, andengine

I am using andengine to develop my game and also using entity modifiers to bring some visual effects. Like the menu screen is sliding in from the bottom and so on. But these effects are rather primitive. Is there any library out there to create more advance effects. Like sliding in but in a more elastic way ( like ios windows coming in an out for example)

Comment: have you checked out the Ease functions - they can add some flare.

Comment: no i did not... i even dont know what is that

Comment: ok it looks like what i want :) if you write it as an answer i will be happy to accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Ease functions - there are many - takes a while to choose the one you want, but they should suffice for some added flare.